# How do I check if url.createobjecturl generated uri is still active in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, blob, ionic2

Im storing some pictures in my database as blobs.  I display them in my app by using url.createobjecturl() function.

But after some time, these generated images will be cleared, how do I test if these are still active?

If they are active keep using them, if not active then re-build the uri.

Im using ionic 2, angular 2 with typescript.

Comment: Looks like they stick around until the page is unloaded? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: In my up im using local storage to store the url, so I can display that image in multiple locations.  So if someone closes the application and reopens it again, the image might be gone.  Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds like it from the MDN page. You could always [use Canvas to turn an image into a data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). That wouldn't expire or anything if you store that url, and it can be used in the same ways.

Comment: @MikeSmith did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with JavaScript:

```
fetch(itemObjectURL)
.then(function checkForBlobHealth(blob){
    if (!blob.ok) {
        console.log('❗ ' + itemObjectURL + ': Local media file not present')
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(itemObjectURL);
        //Take care of the situation
    } else {
        // Move on as usual
    }
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Failed verifying. Details: ' + err);
})
```